# Issue with ContextLoaderListener

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I am getting below errors (ClassNotFoundException) while starting my application (spring+maven) using tomcat8.0.
There is no clue what happens wrong even in logs. Please help out

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1320)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:550)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:531)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4672)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is how I configured listener in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>reporting</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>reporting</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>  
        /WEB-INF/reporting-servlet.xml,  
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/dao-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Application was working fine, issue arises when I added a new maven module to the project. Now even removing the module is causing the same problem.

pom.xml dependencies below:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Did you see "ClassNotFoundException"?

Comment: Yes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Comment: Did you check that war placed in tomcat has spring-web-<version>.jar?

Comment: spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real issue seems to be with version of jar files I have in my pom.xml file.
Using same version of various spring jars resolved the issue.
This post was helpful in resolving the issue.
[Which maven dependencies to include for spring 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237537/which-maven-dependencies-to-include-for-spring-3-0)