# Tomcat - Exception when I try to share two projects on two different ports

Tags: tomcat

I have two webservice a SOAP (Axis2) and the other type REST (Jersey 2).

Everything works fine, but I want to put one on port 8080 and one on port 8081.

I started edit my server.xml inside my tomcat/conf folder for create a new service with his own connector, engine and host like this :

server.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
<Listener SSLEngine="on"
    className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved"
        factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase"
        pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
<Service name="reciver">
    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="10000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="10" port="8080" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="host1" name="reciver"> 
        <Host autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
            <Context docBase="SOAP" path="/SOAP" reloadable="true"
                source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SOAP" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="reciver2">
    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="10000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="10" port="8081" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="host2" name="reciver2"> 
        <Host autoDeploy="true"  name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
            <Context docBase="REST" path="/REST" reloadable="true"
                source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:REST" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

I have a problem with my context on the second Service. When i add this one and try to launch Tomcat i got this exception :

```
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[reciver2].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/REST]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[reciver2].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/REST]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5e8549c9]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5039)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\DEV\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\REST] is not valid
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more

déc. 09, 2015 11:23:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[reciver2].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[reciver2].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

déc. 09, 2015 11:23:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[reciver2]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[reciver2]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
```

When i delete the context tomcat launch and listen on this port.

[image: port]

This is the first time i try to do that, I'm doing something wrong, but I do not know where I search on google and stack but I have not found the solution.

I working on windows 10, tomcat 8 and eclipse Mars.

If one of you knows the solution I will be grateful to him for help. Thank you

Comment: I think it is the Eclipse WTP causing you trouble. Have you tried to run a Tomcat with the same configuration but manually deploying files? Also have you found exactly *where* your REST project gets deployed? Clearly not where Tomcat looks for it: `C:\DEV\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\REST`.

Comment: Don't post pictures of test here. Post the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You problem is that you are trying to start Tomcat with such configuration from within Eclipse IDE.

Ghayel is right that the following is the main reason:

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\DEV\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\REST] is not valid
>  at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:723)
>  at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:684)
>  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> ```

See [Eclipse IDE](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q6) in Tomcat FAQ and [Eclipse WebTools Project Tomcat FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ) at Eclipse for references.

You problem is caused by combination of the following two facts:

1. By default Eclipse IDE does not use the `server.xml` file that you are editing in your IDE, but it processes it when copying into different 'CATALINA_BASE' directory. From your log message that directory is `C:\DEV\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps`.

   First, look at `conf/server.xml` file in that directory. It may be different from the file that you edited.

   Second, I would expect that Eclipse IDE processing of `server.xml` does not support multiple Engine elements. (It may support them, but I will be surprised if it does so).
2. When `Context` element is defined in server.xml, failure to start this context results in a startup failure of Tomcat as a whole.

   This is one of the reasons not to define Context elements in `server.xml`.

AFAIK, a Tomcat server in Eclipse can be configured to use a different CATALINA_BASE directory, and it can be configured to publish contexts as xml files (instead of putting them into `server.xml`), but I still doubt that such configuration supports multiple Engine elements.

I think your best bet is to configure a Tomcat instance outside of Eclipse and use other tools (such as Apache Ant) to pack and deploy your web application there (either by copying the files + relying on autodeploy, or by using [Tomcat Ant tasks](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_using_the_Client_Deployer_Package) to deploy an application onto a running Tomcat instance).

If you do not need for these web services to be on the same JVM, just configure several Server instances in Eclipse and start them in parallel. (Of course, their port numbers must be different).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are running your Tomcat from Eclipse with the Server plugin.
Be aware that the plugin might do some magic. E.g. it will set appBase to wtpwebapps for the first `<Host>` element.

So your first Host element in your config (`/Service[@name="reciver"]/Engine/Host`) has the attribute implicitly set to appBase="wtpwebapps" whereas the second Host element (`/Service[@name="reciver2"]/Engine/Host`) has appBase="webapps". So for the second host the webapp is not found since it looks in the wrong place.

This is what line ~25 in your log tells you:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\DEV\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\REST] is not valid`

You have different options:

1) add appBase="wtpwebapps" to your second Host, however this will make both webapps available on both ports 8080 and 8081.

2) achieve the same result as in 1) by adding a second connector to `<Service name="reciver"...` and removing the second service.

3) add a third service, one that is configured by eclipse and the other two are controlled by you, compare config below. This lets Eclipse configure the first service and exposes the different webapps on the two other ports 8080 and 8081 with the drawback of having both webapps available on 8888.

4) you can play around with combinations, just be aware that the first Host is configured by Eclipse.

I would recommend 2) for development. 3) and 1) interfere somewhat with the WTP plugin e.g. when adding/removing modules to a server or getting out of sync.

Solution 2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
<Listener SSLEngine="on"
    className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />


<Service name="forEclipse">
    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="10000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="10" port="8080" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />

    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="10000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="10" port="8081" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="host1" name="reciver">
        <Host autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

            <Context docBase="SOAP" path="/SOAP" reloadable="true"
                source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SOAP" />
            <Context docBase="REST" path="/REST" reloadable="true"
                source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:REST" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Solution 3)

```
<Service name="forEclipse">
    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="10000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="10" port="8888" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="host1" name="reciver">
        <Host autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

            <Context docBase="SOAP" path="/SOAP" reloadable="true"
                source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SOAP" />
            <Context docBase="REST" path="/REST" reloadable="true"
                source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:REST" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>

<Service name="reciver">
    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="10000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="10" port="8080" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="host1" name="reciver">
        <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost"
            unpackWARs="true">

            <Context docBase="../wtpwebapps/SOAP" path="/SOAP"
                reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SOAP" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="reciver2">
    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="10000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="10" port="8081" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="host2" name="reciver2">
        <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost"
            unpackWARs="true">
            <Context docBase="../wtpwebapps/REST" path="/REST"
                reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:REST" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Answer (score -1):

After reading your `server.xml` configuration and review Apache Tomcat 8 official documentation for:

- [Service](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/service.html)
- [Engine](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/engine.html)
- [Host](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html)
- [Context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html)

I can tell you the following: Your `Server`, `Service` and `Engine` configuration seems right.

However, both `Host` configuration lack **appBase** attribute, <strike>which is marked as mandatory into official documentation</strike>. The same for `Context` **docBase** attribute, <strike>it is mandatory and</strike> it is not present in your sample config. (**EDIT**: Cross Out thanks to @EJP comment)

Furthermore, `Context` config states the following about **docBase** attribute:

> The **Document Base** (also known as the Context Root) directory for this web application, or the pathname to the web application archive file (if this web application is being executed directly from the WAR file). You may specify an absolute pathname for this directory or WAR file, or a pathname that is relative to the appBase directory of the owning Host.

I see none of them in your sample configuration.

On the other hand, official doc states about `Context` the following:

> **It is NOT recommended to place <Context> elements directly in the server.xml file**. This is because it makes modifying the **Context** configuration more invasive since the main `conf/server.xml` file cannot be reloaded without restarting Tomcat.

So, please review your configuration, because I found some mistakes which can be causing your `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start`

Comment: The word 'mandatory' does not appear in your [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html). What it actually says about `appBase` is " If not specified, the default of `webapps` will be used.".

Comment: You are right, I am sorry. Both attributes appear in bold font, so both are very important. I forgot to say that there are similar errors in SO related with **docBase** and **appBase**, so I wanted to emphasize this, but I did it wrong. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score -3):

This is the main reason:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\DEV\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\REST] is not valid
```

Here you can fix it [Issue with ContextLoaderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465966/issue-with-contextloaderlistener)

Comment: @JoffreyHernandez I not understand ==>Bug thank you for tout anwser??

Comment: @Ghayel Joffrey meant "big thank you for your answer."

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the real problem. You link to a question with a `ClassNotFoundException` instead the problem described.

Comment: I'm sorry my autocorrect french keyboard on my cell phone made this.I meant "But thank you for your answer".

Comment: Have you checked the answer in the referred post that is not mentioning CNF exception but stating that Real issue seems to be with version of jar files I have in my pom.xml file. Using same version of various spring jars resolved the issue. This post was helpful in resolving the issue. Which maven dependencies to include for spring 3.0?

Comment: also the answer in the referred post like you to another post